# Where to set sitecore layout and sub-layout

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.2

I am a newbie to sitecore and wanted to ask a question about layout inheritance.  I am using web forms and do all my work using Sitecore Rocks.  I have a base template that has three fields.  I also have 2 other templates (Hardware and Product) that inherit from the base template.  I have created a Hardware content item and under it is a Product content item.

I created my layout, sub-layout, and their respective definition item. In my layout I have a placeholder control so I can dynamically bind a component to it.

Now, I went ahead set the layout and sub-layout to the standard values of the base template.  Now, by me doing this, will both the Hardware and Product items inherit the layout and sub-layout?  I think the answer is yes because when I preview both items, they render per the layout and sub-layout I defined. Is this a standard practice?  Also, if I define a different sub-layout for the Product item and set it to the standard values of the Product template, how come I get "...layout not found" error message when the layout is defined on its base template?

If someone could shed a light on this for me, I would appreciate it.  I really want to get this concept down as I realize that it's the building block to Sitecore development.

Comment: Does the newly added sublayout to the Product Item available on the Presentation Details?

Comment: Please use the correct Sitecore version in your tags... you have 7.2 and 8 in there making it hard to determine what you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question is **YES**, if you create a base template with some __StandardValues and you inherit the  Product and Hardware templates from the base template, without defining their own standard values, any content items created from these templates will inherit the `presentation details` from the base template.

To answer your second question, you get a Layout not found, probably because you haven't defined a layout on the `__StandardValues` of the **Product** template, as you expect to be inherited from Base. But it does not work this way.

Let me explain:

---

In my screenshot below, you can see the three templates you mentioned. Note that:

[image]

- **BaseTemplate** has `__StandardValues`
- **ProductTemplate** inherits from Base but has **no** `__StandardValues`

  > Any content items created from this template will inherit form the StandardValues of the Base template, as no custom values exist
- **HardwareTemplate** inherits from Base but has it's own `_StandardValues`

  > Any content items created from this template will not inherit from Base, it will use its own settings from _StandardValues

As soon as you change the Presentation Details of an item, your item will keep your changes.

A very detailed explanation on how Standard Values work can be found here: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/all-about-standard-values-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Comment: @Adrianlorgu, are you sure about this?  I just set this up again on clean instance of Sitecore and if I set the presentation detail on the `_StandardValues` of **BaseTemplate**, items created from the **ProductTemplate** and **HardwareTemplate** are inheriting the presentation detail from **BaseTemplate** regardless of the existence of `_StandardValues` on the templates inheriting from `BaseTemplate`.  I am checking this by selecting the item and going to the presentation tab and clicking on the details option.

Comment: On which Sitecore version are you testing this? Before I've answered your questions, I did simulate this on a Sitecore 8 solution, as you added the sitecore8 tag to your post. It works as described for me

Comment: I am testing this on Sitecore 8.  Exact steps are:  1. Created the BaseTemplate.  2. Created the standard values on BaseTemplate.  3. Created ProductTemplate (inherits from BaseTemplate), added one field but no standard values.  4. Created HardwareTemplate (inherits from BaseTemplate), added one field and added standard values.  5. Assigned a presentation detail to the standard value of BaseTemplate.  6. Created a content item of type Hardware and Product.  7. When viewing the presentation details for both content items, I see that they both have inherited the one from the BaseTemplate.

Comment: You must do something wrong. Just tried every single step on a clean Sitecore 8.1 installation. Maybe you define the _StandardValues the wrong way. I've created a installation package with my example above. Install it and have a look at the mentioned behavior   https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/21143a8fa099e9c6d65ed51b237af7f220160604133650/76829ffefc3029b0813051dc8ca4d0e220160604133650/5fd645

Comment: I installed your package and looked at it.  There was a misunderstanding in that I wasn't setting a presentation detail on the standard values of any of the templates except the base template.  I think we are saying the same thing.  I see from your sample that if I set a presentation detail on the standard values of a template, it will override the presentation detail from the base template.  Thanks for your help in this.